# hadoop use cases with Valid Loan Data

Tags: hadoop, use-case

I have some - important data sets for **loan Acquisitions in the TXT file** 
Note- Data are available to me for Q1-Q4 for last 3 years.

Also Please find the Field description of each column for the Acquisitions File in the Image file.

1) Can you please help me to generate - **some VALID Logical Business use cases** which I want to implement using HDFS and Mapreduce JAVA programming.

Because Most of the sample use cased - related to word count and weather data analysis.

To get the data file - just do a sign in

### Data - File

Link ----------  **loanperformancedata.fanniemae.com/lppub-docs/acquisition-sample-file.txt**

**100009503314|CORRESPONDENT|WELLS FARGO BANK, N.A.|3.75|320000|360|12/2011|02/2012|67|67|1|32|798|NO|PURCHASE|PUD|1|PRINCIPAL|CA|949||FRM**

100010175842|RETAIL|OTHER|3.875|255000|360|02/2012|04/2012|73|73|1|49|778|NO|NO CASH-OUT REFINANCE|SF|1|PRINCIPAL|OH|432||FRM

**100013227768|BROKER|FLAGSTAR CAPITAL MARKETS CORPORATION|3.875|415000|360|12/2011|03/2012|46|46|2|21|780|NO|NO CASH-OUT REFINANCE|PUD|1|PRINCIPAL|VA|223||FRM**

100016880542|RETAIL|WELLS FARGO BANK, N.A.|4.25|417000|360|11/2011|012012|90|90|2|40|794|NO|PURCHASE|SF|1|PRINCIPAL|CA|956|25|FRM

### 2) Column description of the data

link -  **loanperformancedata.fanniemae.com/lppub-docs/lppub_file_layout.pdf**

LOAN IDENTIFIER
CHANNEL
SELLER NAME
ORIGINAL INTEREST RATE
ORIGINAL UNPAID PRINCIPAL BALANCE (UPB)
ORIGINAL LOAN TERM
ORIGINATION DATE
FIRST PAYMENT DATE
ORIGINAL LOAN-TO-VALUE (LTV)
ORIGINAL COMBINED LOAN TO -VALUE
NUMBER OF BORROWERS
DEBT - TO -INCOME RATIO
CREDIT SCORE
FIRST -TIME HOME BUYER INDICATOR
LOAN PURPOSE
PROPERTY TYPE
NUMBER OF UNITS
OCCUPANCY STATUS
PROPERTY STATE
ZIP (3-DIGIT)
MORTGAGE INSURANCE PERCENTAGE
PRODUCT TYPE

link ------- >**loanperformancedata.fanniemae.com/lppub-docs/lppub_glossary.pdf**

Please help me - to build some valid Business use cases and Java program to implement the same.

Most of the Data for - Hadoop are - Weather count and Word count example :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple filtering and aggregation to identify a state having maximum number of loans and minimum credit score. That may give an insight to identify issues in approving loans where default rate is much higher.